# Getting multiple keys using node-redis

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, redis, node-redis

I'm trying to get a bunch of keys from a redis instance. I'm using node-redis. I'm using a loop:

```
for( var i=1; i<=num; ++i ){
    client.get(key + ':' + num, function (err, reply) {
        obj[num] = reply;
    });
}
return obj;
```

But `obj` is just undefined. I feel like I may be having problems because `get` is obviously called asynchronously. Is there another way to achieve this? Should I just store the values in a sorted set instead?

Comment: Where is `obj` declared?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm going to hazard a guess based on the coding interface and your comments that `client.get()` is asynchronous.  That means that it calls the callback function passed to it "sometime later", not immediately.  Thus, you can't use synchronous coding patterns to collect the results from multiple calls to `client.get()` because the results in `obj` are not yet available when your function returns.  Thus `obj` is not yet populated with the results.

If you want to know when multiple asychronous calls are done, then you have to code a very different way.  And, the results will ONLY be available inside the callback functions, not at the end of your function.

In all, I see multiple problems with your code:

1. `client.get()` is asynchronous so it hasn't finished yet when your function returns
2. You should probably be using `i`, not `num` in your `client.get()` call so that each time through the `for` loop generates a different request.
3. The value of `i` in the loop has to be frozen in a closure in order to retain it's value for use in the callback function that is called later.
4. If `obj` was actually undefined, then that may be because you didn't initialize it to an empty object.

Here's one way to do it:

```
var obj = {};
var remaining = num;
for( var i=1; i<=num; ++i ){
    // create a closure here to freeze the value of i in the callback
    (function(i) {
        client.get(key + ':' + i, function (err, reply) {
            obj[i] = reply;
            // see if all asynch calls are done yet
            --remaining;
            if (remaining === 0) {
                // all asynch calls to client.get() are done now
                // in here, you can use the obj object and the results put on it
            }
        });
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: Yeah I figured it may be an async problem. And the `i` vs `num` thing was just a mistake I made typing the questions. And your solution works beautifully thank you.